# terraform plan wants to destroy security groups after importing them with terraform import

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

Occurs to me in version 0.9.4 and 0.10.4

I imported a list of AWS security groups using Terraform's import command as follows:

```
terraform import aws_security_group.production_servers sg-xxxxxxx
```

When I do:

```
terraform plan aws_security_group.production_servers
```

everything is fine but when I do a general plan:

```
terraform plan

- aws_security_group_rule.load_balancer_1

- aws_security_group_rule.load_balancer_1-1

- aws_security_group_rule.load_balancer_1-2

- aws_security_group_rule.load_balancer_1-3

- aws_security_group_rule.production_servers

- aws_security_group_rule.production_servers-1

- aws_security_group_rule.production_servers-2

- aws_security_group_rule.production_servers-3

- aws_security_group_rule.production_services_access

- aws_security_group_rule.production_services_access-1

- aws_security_group_rule.production_services_access-2
```

Some `aws_security_group_rule`(persisted in my .tfstate file) are going to be deleted.

I'm declaring the security groups using `aws_security_group` with `ingress` and `egress` per rule. Not sure whether to declare those `aws_security_group_rule`s because of this.

Not sure what I'm missing, any guidance would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the import for network ACL and security group break things out like

```
resource "aws_security_group" "production_servers" {}
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "production_servers-1" {}
resource "aws_security_group_rule" "production_servers" {}
```

You mentioned you had all the rules in the `aws_security_group` which is perfectly fine. I prefer them outside since its more readable if you make a rule change and have like 10-15 rules in a group.

So whats going on is terraform wrote a blank `aws_security_group` with no rules and has a bunch of external `aws_security_group_rule` in the state file which is different then your TF config.

So on a plan it'll say I need to destroy these and then it will create them in the resource itself.

You might get a minor blip of no security group rules but in the end it'll clean up on an apply. Just look at the plan for your `aws_security_group` I would bet all your rules are listed in there

Comment: What you mean is that as I declared the `aws_security_group` and no `aws_security_group_rule`s in my .tf files, it is going to be fine to let terraform destroy those ones because `aws_security_group` is already defining the ingress and egress, right?

Comment: when you import terraform expects the rules are defined outside the group. So it adds them to the state file that way. So your plan doesn't have it that way and they are inside the group so its going to destroy them first.. if they are defined inside the group it will re-create them